# Nim ui (libui) error

Tags: nim-lang

I tried to compile "controllgallery2.nim" , but ..

> Error: execution of an external compiler program 'gcc.exe -c -w -mno-ms-bitfields -IC:\Users(User name)\Documents\Language\Nim\nim-0.18.0\lib -o G:\Nim \nimcache\win_debug.cpp.obj C:\Users(User name).nimble\pkgs\ui-0.9.2\ui./libui/windows\debug.cpp' failed with exit code: 1 C:\Users\terur.nimble\pkgs\ui-0.9.2\ui./libui/windows\debug.cpp: In function 'void realbug(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, con st char*, va_list)': C:\Users(User name).nimble\pkgs\ui-0.9.2\ui./libui/windows\debug.cpp:76:31: error: 'vsprintf_s' was not declared in this scope vsprintf_s(msg, n, format, ap); ^

What I should do to fix that error?

Comment: Format your text.

Comment: have you tried using visual studio for compilation? it looks like it cannot find `vsprintf_s`, which is available (only?) for that compiler.

Comment: What was your compilation command? You need `nim cpp file.nim` for getting this working, afaik.

Comment: There are two prototypes for vsprintf_s, one that require using a cpp compiler.
Since it has four and not three args, it correspond to the c function.
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsprintf-s-vsprintf-s-l-vswprintf-s-vswprintf-s-l?view=msvc-170
It tries to compile .cpp files with gcc ! <stdarg.h> is a required header and might be missing.
Don't use nim ui library anymore, it wraps a C library on hiatus, see :
https://github.com/nim-lang/ui/issues/43